# jquery ajax calling servlet method and return json data

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I am new to Ajax programming I am using Jquery ajax my requirement to to fetch the data into server and display as table format.In that location must display radio button type.
how to call servlet specific method how to return data.i am ready to use json.can any one help me how to call a method how to return a data.and suggestions require to solve the problem

thanks in advance.

```
$('#ajaxbutton').on('click',function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"Db2",
                    data:{"labid",100},
                    sucess:function(){
                        alert("sucess");
                    }

                });
            });
```

in servlet

```
public class Db2 extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        doProcess(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        doProcess(request, response);
    }

    public void doProcess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException {
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement ps, ps1;
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:oracle1", "system",
                    "sarath");
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select trackid,location,to_char(mydate,'dd-mon-yyyy') from information where labid=100");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String location = rs.getString(2);
                String track = rs.getString(1);
                String myDate = rs.getString(3);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }

    }
}// end of ServletB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
while (rs.next()) {
    String location = rs.getString(2);
    String track = rs.getString(1);
    String myDate = rs.getString(3);
    res.append("{");
    res.append("'location':");
    res.append(location);
    res.append(",");
    res.append("'track':");
    res.append(track);
    res.append(",");
    res.append("'myDate ':");
    res.append("myDate ");
    res.append("}");
}
out.println(res.toString());
```

must be json-string and the ajax can use `eval("data = "+r_data+";");`

Comment: it is returning json string i converted JSON.parse() now i want display a table format first record must be input type radio

Comment: display first record？ 
loop json datas to get first record...is it?(是这个意思吗?)

Comment: {'location':hyderbad,'track':12345,'myDate ':15-dec-2013}{'location':sydny,'track':2322,'myDate ':21-jan-2014}  retuning data in this format it is showing error parse to json

Comment: {'location':'hyderbad','track':'12345','myDate ':'15-dec-2013'}{'location':'sydny','track':'2322','myDate ':'21-jan-2014'} it is json data style

Comment: it needs "," from one object another object

Comment: [{'location':'hyderbad','track':'12345','myDate ':'15-dec-2013'},{'location':'sydny','track':'2322','myDate ':'21-jan-2014'}] ...the json is working, oooooye

Answer (score 2):

*how to call servlet specific method* 
In your ajax you are writing `type=post` so in the servlet `doPost()` will be called.if it would have been `type=get` then servlet `doGet()` method will be called.So you should write the database retrieve part in the specific method.

Now suppose you want location,track and mydate then try this way
In the servlet

```
PrintWriter out.response.getWriter();
out.println(location);
out.println(track);
out.println(mydate);
```

In the ajax success part do this way

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                       alert(data);
```

Comment: can i use any other method in the type insted of get/post and can i write return "json"; in method. i am using only servlet for entire application

Comment: see in servlet doPost or doGet will be called as per the form method(i.e get or post).

Comment: thanks it is working fine but i have doubt if i use so many data base quiries in one servlet how to differentiate only that method . generally we write   public String method(){ return "jsonstring";}   but here not possible to write return statement but unnecessarily calling entire servlet

Comment: @sarath sorry could not understand

Comment: thanks it is working fine but i have doubt if i use so many data base quiries in one servlet how to differentiate only that method . generally we write   public String method(){ return "jsonstring";}   to call just write method();  but here not possible to write return statement .

Comment: @sarath you can write out.println(method());

Comment: oh thanks ..then i understand data displayed based on out.println